# AccessVBA INPUT INTO qry and the dreaded error 2342

Tags: vba, ms-access, syntax-error

After spending numerous hours searching the web for answers (stackoverflow coming the closest) yet not finding the exact solution; I'm posing this question as best I can.

This is string dynamically created to be executed by `DoCmd.runSQL`

```
INSERT INTO rf_SKU 
  (UPC, SKU, Sex , Color , Size, Width, MakerID, ModelID) 
VALUES 
  ('889961356902', '411160.TBTB', 'M', 'TRUE BLUE', 07.00, 'D', 6, 247);
```

`<there are 8 fields; Size, MakerID, ModelID are numeric integer>`

I tried 'every' variation of syntax; all producing same error 2342.

Syntax rules that I wasn't 100% confident about but I think are correct now:

- parentheticals around the Values
- apostrophes around numerical values

I am baffled to say the least, begging for help, and praying for an answer.

Many thanks and grand wishes of wellness to those that can help.

ADD INFO: In debugging I did do the paste-qryStr-into-SQLview thing then look at Design View.  This statement worked fine in that interface; however, Access changed "VALUES" to "SELECT" and added "Expression1." (or 2, 3, etc.) to the string.  I tried mimicking this format in VBA..still no luck.

Comment: can you post the code that creates your sql string?

Comment: What is datatype for field `Width`?

Comment: If Size is Integer, you can't insert a Float `07.00` into it.

Comment: Also see [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Comment: @ArcherBird... thanks for taking a look!!  here is the string build....qrySKU = "INSERT INTO rf_SKU (UPC, SKU, Sex , Color , Size, Width, MakerID, ModelID) "
qrySKU = qrySKU & "VALUES ('" & rsVen.Fields(5) & "', '" & Left(rsVen.Fields(2), 11) & "', '" & Jender & "', '" & rsVen.Fields(4) & "', "
qrySKU = qrySKU & Left(Right(rsVen.Fields(2), 4), 2) & "." & Right(Right(rsVen.Fields(2), 4), 2) & ", '" & Width & "', " & rsmkrmod.Fields(2) & ", " & rsmkrmod.Fields(3) & ");"
<<sorry about formatting...new to this>>

Comment: @Harun24HR  thx for help... just confirmed that the datatype for Width is ShortText... ( I am working with shoe store inventory)

Comment: @Andre... AH!!  Excellent point!!!  Thanks a bunch....will check out the article and test your theory...

Comment: @HansUp...???  the statement i posed is copy&paste from debug.print output... i use DP alot to test as I build...but I'm def not a pro at this stuff...  thanks for the perspective tho... will check it out

Comment: if this is inserting into an Access table, your string values in the `VALUES` clause should be enclosed in double quotes, not single. It would be most helpful if you could edit your post to show all vba code that builds the string holding your sql query, and executes the `Do.Cmd` on it - just to make sure you are passing things around correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If this is meant to insert into an Access table, your string values in the `VALUES` clause should be enclosed in double quotes, not single. Based on what you posed in your comments about the string builder - it would be something like this to build the string holding your sql...

```
    Dim qrySKU As String
    qrySKU = "INSERT INTO rf_SKU (UPC, SKU, Sex , Color , Size, Width, MakerID, ModelID) "
    qrySKU = qrySKU & "VALUES (""" & rsVen.Fields(5) & """, """ & Left(rsVen.Fields(2), 11) & """, """ & Jender & """, """ & rsVen.Fields(4) & """, "
    qrySKU = qrySKU & Left(Right(rsVen.Fields(2), 4), 2) & "." & Right(Right(rsVen.Fields(2), 4), 2) & ", """ & Width & """, " & rsmkrmod.Fields(2) & ", " & rsmkrmod.Fields(3) & ");"
```

Comment: oh wow!!  I bet you are CORRECT...I've spent the last couple of hours (running a biz so i get lots of interruptions)....last couple of hours re-coding to build querydef and execute...which has worked....  i will def do some test code to see if you are correct.  Thanks!